# How to perform Prais-Winsten autoregression in SPSS 16?

Tags: autocorrelation, autoregressive

When performing a linear regression on my dataset, Durbin-Watson was very low (0.276). I found a tutorial online that suggested performing an Prais-Winston autocorrelation. The tutoral came with screenshots of SPSS on how to perform the analysis. The screenshots however, are from SPSS 14. I have SPSS 16, and I am not able to find the same test anywhere in my menu structure.

Please see the tutorials screenshots (above) and mine (below) here: [image: http://i.imgur.com/gN0jG.png]

Can someone direct me to where the Prais-Winsten autoregression can be found in SPSS 16?

Comment: I believe the Prais-Winston autoregression assumes errors are AR(1). For SPSS command line syntax see the AREG command. Depending on the extent of the serial-correlation, ARIMA models might need to be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog box interface was removed when the time series Expert Modeler was released.  You might want to consider using that instead, but the AREG command remains in the system through syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Use the command AREG as below

File > New > Syntax

in the opened syntax file type the following stuff, suppose that var1 is the dep. var. and var2 is the indep. variable:

AREG var1 with var2.

select all by mouse draging and click on the button Run  >>>>finish